# fork and signal: how to send signals from parent process to specific child process

Tags: c, linux, signals, fork, kill

I need to `fork` two child-processes. One can receive the signal 3, print `hello` and send the signal 4 to the the other child process; The other can receive the signal 4, print `world` and send the signal 3 to the first child process.
To start, the father process will send the signal 3 to the first child process after sleeping for 3 seconds.
Then 3 seconds later, the father process will send `SIGKILL` to kill both of them.

I don't know how to send signals to a specific child process (I knew that we had a function `kill` to send signals but I don't know to use it here).

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void func(int n)
{
        printf("ping\n");
        // how to send signal 4 to the second process?
}

void func2(int n)
{
        printf("pong\n");
        // how to send signal 3 to the first process?
}

int main()
{
        pid_t pid;
        int i;
        for(i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
                pid = fork();
                if(pid == 0)
                {
                        if(i == 0)
                        {
                                signal(3, func);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                signal(4, func2);
                        }
                        while(1);
                }
                else
                {
                        if(i == 1)
                        {
                                sleep(3);
                                // how to send signal 3 to the first child process?
                                sleep(3);
                                // how to kill the two children?
                        }
                }
        }


        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Undefined behavior for calling `printf()` in a signal context.

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html

Comment: @EOF  What should I do then?

Comment: @alk   But I still don't know how to send signals to child processes.

Comment: The `kill()` system call is what you need. The tricky part is that you have to tell each child about the PID of its sibling somehow. Maybe the parent tells them both by writing the information on a pipe?  Or maybe you use process groups to do the signaling.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  Yes, in fact this is what I don't know how to do. Maybe you are right, I have to use a pipe or a shared memory.

Comment: @user3629249   Thanks a lot. If you wish, you could answer this question and I ll accept your answer.

Comment: moved my comments to an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use the popen() function to open a process by forking and opening a pipe to that process (instead of using fork() directly)

The parent knows the PID of each process so can then easily pass the pid of the second child to the first child.

The first child can use the pid and the kill()` function to pass a signal to the second child.

SO, use popen() to start the first child. use fork() to start the second child, then pass the pid from the second child to the first via the stream created with popen().

the handling of the pid value returned from the call to fork() is not being handled correctly.

The posted code is making the assumption that the call to fork() was successful... This is not a safe/valid assumption

The code also needs to check for the pid being -1 and appropriately handling that error.

when a child process completes, it should NOT sit in a `while()` loop but rather exit, using the `exit()` function.

The parent, should not just exit, as that leaves the two child processes as zombies. (zombies are very difficult to get rid of short of a system reboot.)

Rather, the parent should call `wait()` or even better `waitpid()` (and remember the child processes need to actually exit, NOT sit in a `while()` loop.

1) the `func()` and `func2()` should check the parameter to assure that it was the correct signal that was being processed.

2) the man page for `signal()` indicates that it should not be used. The man page suggest using: `sigaction()`,

Answer (score 0):

When you `fork` you get the new `pid`. Per the [kill manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/2/kill) you call `kill(pid_t pid, int sig);` using the `pid`

Comment: If I write `kill(pid, 3)` after the first `sleep(3)`, I think it will send to all children processes. What I need is to send to the first child process.

Comment: @Thomas: no; it sends the signal to one process unless you use a zero or negative value for `pid`.

Comment: OK. I got it. I have another problem: how to share the pids between the processes? Because I need to `kill(4, secondProcessPid)` in `func` and `kill(3, firstProcessPid)` in `func2`. How to get these two pids? Must I use something like shared memory?

Comment: You have your arguments to `kill` backward....  Shared memory would seem to be overkill in this case.   When you `fork()`, the child process is a copy of the parent.  That includes global and local variables.